# how to display pop up text on mouse over in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have an image on clicking it deletes a user ,i want to display the text pop up message delete on mouse over .the code is below.

```
<a href=<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?remove_user=1&userid=".$i ?>"> <img src="images/delete.png" width="15" height="15" alt="remove user details"    style="border:0px;line-height:0px;margin:0px;"/>
</a>
```

how to do this.

Comment: You should POST for requests that modify state on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most browsers will display text you enter in a "title" attribute as a tooltip: ie

```
<a href="http://someurl.info" title="This will appear on a hover">Link text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the message into the `title` attribute of the `a` element.

Comment: i have added title="remove" in a tag .then how to proceed next can you explain me

Comment: That's usually all you need. If it does not work, then the reason might be that you are not producing valid HTML.

Comment: ok thanks i got that .browsers only display the message in title